# Unknown Property Error at Primefaces FileUpload

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, event-listener

I am using PF 3.0.RC1 / NetBeans 7.0.1 and when I try to set fileUploadListener for fileUpload component , NetBeans gives this warning "Unknown Property 'handleFileUpload' " at leftmost of line.

In debug mode when I use fileUpload , it don't call handleFileUpload method and nothing becomes.

What can I do for this problem ?

The code in the xhtml page :

```
 <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{BDS_System.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" 
                        sizeLimit="500000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>
```

The code in the managed bean :

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        String fileName = event.getFile().getFileName();
        byte[] fileBytes = event.getFile().getContents();

        ...
    }
```

**Solved and solution :**

Adding

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and two libraries ,commons-fileupload and commons-io .For maven projects ;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId> commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId> commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess that it is that just like in BalusC answer in this thread: ["Unknown Property"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432723/netbeans-tells-unknown-property-on-ppoll-listener) the error message of netbeans is nonsense , I think you forgot something in the fileupload config , like the

> #### Getting started with FileUpload
>
> First thing to do is to configure the fileupload filter which parses the multipart request. FileUpload filter should map to Faces Servlet.
>
> ```xml
> <filter>
>     <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
> </filter>
> <filter-mapping>
>     <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
>     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

and make sure to add enctype to your form like this:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

if all of the above wont help , take a look at BalusC answer in here: [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked)

Comment: thanks ! I added this <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data"> and also added two library  commons-fileupload and commons-io so it worked :)